# Schema Conversion in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, converters

Let's assume, I have a sample class `foo` with an attribute `bar`. I have set annotations for JAXB, so I can export it to XML and re-import it again.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class foo {
    private int bar;

    @XmlElement()
    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

The XML file should look somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar>5</bar>
</foo>
```

Now I have learned, I can also make `bar` an attribute. Using `@XmlAttribute` instead would make it look like `<foo bar="5"/>`, which I would prefer?

I already have a lot of files using the old schema. Changing them by hand would be very cumbersome, so I'd like to do it automatically.

Does JAXB offer a convenient way to convert the files? Maybe different annotations for unmarshalling and marshalling? What else could I do to achieve this without too much effort?

Comment: do you mean you have bunch of xml files with `<bar>5</bar>`?

Comment: @pirho yes and i want to convert them to <foo bar="5">, so I can use them with the XmlAttribute annotation

Comment: maybe just some simple file replace regexp stuff would be more suitable if it is not something you do daily? but you want to do it java jaxb way?

Comment: @pirho It has do be done once and not with too much effort. I do not insist on doing it using JAXB, but i thought, this could be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert with JAXB and there propably is more elegant solution. But here is anyway one - maybe not so elegant - solution.

In `class foo` you will anyway change the

```
@XmlElement()
public int getBar() {
```

to

```
@XmlAttribute()    
public int getBar() {
```

You could then inherit `foo` for unmarshalling the old files

```
@XmlRootElement
public class foo2 extends foo {

    @Override
    @XmlElement()    
    public int getBar() {
        return super.getBar();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBar(int bar) {
        super.setBar(bar);
    }
}
```

Then it might be possible to marshall `foo2` as its super `foo` by

`JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(foo.class);`